# How can I download music from YouTube and not the video film?

Tags: software-recommendation, youtube

I want to know if is there any programme to download music from YouTube, not video, just audio, like DVDvideosoft in Windows.

Answer (score 8):

A shell script called `youtube-dl` can do this in 1 step. It depends on `ffmpeg`, so you should install that first.

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
wget https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/raw/2012.02.27/youtube-dl 
chmod +x youtube-dl
./youtube-dl -t --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 YOUTUBE_URL_HERE
```

Extra information on choosing quality of download from YouTube, from the man page:

```
 -f FMT, --format=FMT
       Specify the video format (quality) in which to download the video.

       For youtube.com, in particular, the meaning of the format codes is given as:

       WebM video at 480p: 43
       WebM video at 720p: 45
       H264 video in MP4 container at 480p: 18
       H264 video in MP4 container at 720p: 22
       H264 video in MP4 container at 1080p: 37
       H264 video in FLV container at 360p: 34
       H264 video in FLV container at 480p: 35
       H263 video at 240p: 5
       3GP video: 17

       Note that not all videos are available in all formats and that other sites supported by youtube-dl may have different conventions for their video formats.

       By default, youtube-dl will download the best available format; if you want to download the worst format to save bandwidth and time, use "-f" worst.
```

So add `-f 18` to get h264 mp4 at 480p

Comment: why it downloading .flv ???

Comment: it downloads the best available video source and then converts to mp3 using ffmpeg.

Comment: and what if i don't want the best source

Comment: I doubt youtube stores the audio tracks of video seperately, unless someone knows something different then I'm all ears.  This is the best/easiest way I know, it does the job and leaves you with 1 audio file.  Let the user decide

Comment: Alternatively you can install youtube-dl from the Webupd8 PPA (sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 on the terminal).

Comment: YouTube dl is great!

Answer (score 4):

You can also use jDownloader. just copy the youtube-url, jDownloader will recognize it and will give you the possibility to download all possible formats. Choose only mp3 and it will give you the music only.

https://launchpad.net/~jd-team/+archive/jdownloader

Answer (score 4):

`youtube-dl` can be installed easily:

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl ffmpeg
```

Then simply:

```
youtube-dl -t --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 YOUTUBE_URL_HERE
```

(As [shown here](https://askubuntu.com/a/115597/22949) by duffydack.)

Comment: The installation procedure given here is different.

Answer (score 1):

I have a VM where I installed alsaloop.
I can then use 'normal' recording tools to record audio out as an audio in from the CLI or otherwise.

You can also use this methodology to record audio and video in said VM on any legally purchased audio/video on any site.  It's completely site agnostic and doesn't care what the bearer format is.

Comment: i ll try it! ;)

Comment: Just a heads up, if you do this for video it gets out of sync with the audio.

Answer (score 1):

use can use **download helper** a firefox addon. by this u can directly download videos in mp4,3gp or high quality formats and easy to use.

Comment: The question specifies the music component and **not** the entire video.

Answer (score 0):

If you want batch jobs for many files, it would be better youtube-dl. Although I didn't give a shot.

But this Firefox addon is good for occasional download. Click and look screenshot.  [Firefox Easy Youtube Downloader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-youtube-video-downl-10137/?src=search)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly from the browser using an add-on.

In Google Chrome just go to the Chrome Store (open a new blank tab and click on the grey applications button at the bottom of the screen)

Inside the Chrome Store type Youtube MP3 in the search box

use the second link (it's from YouTube itself)

YouTube Downloader: MP3 / HD Video

Look at the screenshot, you get an extra button in YouTube and you just click download as MP3.

You can do the exact same thing in Firefox. Just go to Tools.. Add-ons... search for 'youtube mp3' and take your pick (there are about 15 choices that do the same thing).

Even better would be use the Ubuntu Music store (inside Rhythmbox and Banshee) to purchase the tracks you like to help support Ubuntu.

Comment: could you please share the name of the addon or extension for chrome or a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

There is an add-on for Firefox that adds a neat button to the Youtube page and gives a few choices:

[Youtube Video and Audio Downloader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-video-and-audio-dow/?src=api)

To get the audio only, you will need to install the package `ffmpeg` from the Ubuntu Software Center, and then go in the add-on options and set the path to ffmpeg as follows:

```
usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

Then it should work without any problem.

In the same add-on options page, you can set the download directory and how the add-on names your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `Youtube to MP3` from the software center. I use it and it's awesome, check out the reviews too.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/youtube-to-mp3/

> Easy-to-use software to download YouTube and Vimeo videos as MP3.

[image]