# Redirect speaker output to microphone

Tags: sound, microphone, speakers, redirect

Can I redirect the output of the speakers to my microphone? I don't want to turn on the speakers.

What I want to achieve is, say I'm doing a video chat and want the other person to listen to the sound. I'd like the sound from the speakers to be routed to the microphone. It'd be helpful while I'm using headphones.

Comment: Probably trying to accomplish this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/115587/how-can-i-download-music-from-youtube-and-not-the-video-film/

Comment: Are you trying to 'mute' speaker output? Or cause feedback damage to audio circuit? *Can you please add **what** you trying to achieve overall to question.*

Comment: @david6 updated the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need only to install Pulse Audio Volume Control

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Open Pulse Audio Volume Control, navigate to the Recording tab and select your application that is recording sound. Then it should provide you with a drop down menu with source options.

Enjoy!

Comment: It worked for me but after selecting `Digital Input` under `Configuration` tab.