# Redirect output audio into microphone without triggering focusout event in browser

Tags: sound, google-chrome, pulseaudio, microphone, redirect

Source1 : Official Web-Application for Video/Audio chatting
Source2 : Skype for outsourced team

Requirement : Wants to redirect all output audio to input mic,

Nearest Solution : [Redirect speaker output to microphone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283687/redirect-speaker-output-to-microphone)

Problem : In Pulseaudio, First we need to start recording and then we can change source in recording menu, 
**But After Start Recording/Chatting in chrome browser, When I try to change inputs in PulseAudio, Application Trigger stop event on focusout event of browser**

Comment: Did you installed pavucontrol as that solution you appointed suggests?

Comment: Yes I installed pavucontrol, It do audio routing when recording is started.
But problem is after recording is started in browser I can't leave browser, otherwise it will automatically stop recording and since recording is stopped option disappear from PulseAudio :(

Comment: You could try to create a bash script to change your source (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21697/amixer-how-to-change-recording-channel), so you assign it to a shortcut-key in Settings> keyboard > Shortcuts.